# Querying items from a category

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, join, recursive-query

DB noob here. I wanted categories with multi-level nested (maybe 3 to 4) categories. eg: Clothings > Men's clothings > Summer wears

So I made recursive categories table.

```
+---------------------------------+
| CATEGORIES                      |
+---------------------------------+
| id <PK>                         |
| parent_id <FK -> CATEGORIES.id> |
| name                            |
+---------------------------------+

+-----------------------------------+
| ITEMS                             |
+-----------------------------------+
| id <PK>                           |
| category_id <FK -> CATEGORIES.id> |
| name                              |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Problem is I don't know how to query all items under 1st level, parent category.

For example, `ITEM 1` is under 2nd level, `Men's clothing (id: 2)` and `ITEM 2` is under 3rd level, `Summer wears (id: 3)`.

I want to see all `ITEM 1` and `ITEM 2` when I query items under `Clothing (id: 1)` which is parent of `Men's clothing` and `Summer wears`.

How do I do that?

Stack: Node.js, Postgres, Knex.js, TypeScript

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive query to list all children of your input category, and then use it to filter the items:

```
with recursive cats as (
    select id from categories where name = ?
    union all
    select c.id 
    from categories c
    inner join cats p on p.id = c.parent_id
)
select i.*
from items i
inner join cats c on c.id = i.category_id
```

The question mark should be replaced with the name of the (parent) category whose items you want to exhibit (in your example, that would be `'Clothing`').